# Flash streaming is not playable in Firefox

Tags: flash

My company is supporting www.poetryarchive.org. Poem players stopped to react in Firefox for the latest Adobe Flash player (11.2.202.228). The buttons are still clickable. But the audio/vidwo are all dead. I've tried it in Chrome. It seems to wrok fine in there. Could anyone having this problem before share his/her idea and solution please?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Zeyin

Answer (score 0):

Good day Zeyin,

I have taken a look at your website with Firefox and everything seems to work fine (flash player 10) after upgrading to the newest player I get the same problems in firefox however in chrome it works fine again.

After checking your source I see a Javascript wich checks the flash version that is where the problem lays because if I kill the Javascript it works in firefox using the newest flash player so this leaves us with 2 possibilities:

- Make the Javascript check the flash player if it is 11.2.202.228 give an error saying that it is not supported yet (dirty)
- Correct the Javascript to make it compatible with the newest version.

I hope you can work further from here.

Greetings, Dennis

Comment: Hi Dennis again, it seems that the JS is just to enforce that the version must be above 10. I'm not so sure it would impact the Flash player. And it works fine in Chrome with the same JS. I wonder could you provide a little bit more details/steps as to how to make it working in FF please?

Comment: The problem isn't actually the JS it is the way the browser compiles it Chrome has better compatibility with flash I guess.. The reason could be that the newest flash player is not fully stable yet therefor I would recommend falling back one release although that shouldn't be THE solution. try optimizing your browser config and just give ff some time to update to this new release probaby in 1 or 2 days it wont occur anymore ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, we've been experiencing this issue for quite a while. And the recent updates (FF 12 beta and Flash player 11.2.202.233) didn't seem to bring any lucks. I raised this issue in FF and Adobe forum too. Still getting nothing back.